# MySql - trying to punctuate a sentence

Tags: mysql, special-characters

Here is my query, which tries to put a full stop at the end of every sentence that doesn't end in proper punctuation

```
UPDATE SentenceTable SET sentence=concat(sentence, '.') WHERE sentence NOT LIKE '%.' OR sentence NOT LIKE '%?' OR sentence NOT LIKE '%!';
```

However, this ends up putting a full stop at the end of every single sentence. I'm afraid I have a problem with the regular expressions from above, maybe I am not escaping some special characters correctly? What am I doing wrong? How should this query read?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `OR` between each of your `sentence NOT LIKE ..` clauses; using `AND` should fix this:

```
UPDATE
    SentenceTable
SET
    sentence=concat(sentence, '.')
WHERE
    sentence NOT LIKE '%.'
    AND sentence NOT LIKE '%?'
    AND sentence NOT LIKE '%!';
```

The reasoning for this is because, assume the `sentence` ends with `!`, such as "This is a sentence!". Your very first clause is `sentence NOT LIKE '%.'`. Well, this sentence doesn't end with a `.`, and because you're only using `OR` the `WHERE`-clause stops parsing the rest of the clauses. When you switch to `AND`, it evaluates *all* of the conditions and since the last one fails, the sentence won't get updated!